# Keras CNN intermediate level has no feature changes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I found that the intermediate layers of my dataset has absolutely no feature changes whatsoever as below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Wheres the examples (cats and dogs) in the [Google ML Crash Course](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part1.ipynb?utm_source=practicum-IC&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&hl=en&utm_content=imageexercise1-colab#scrollTo=-5tES8rXFjux) show a much more fruitful of different features extracted by the CNN as below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And I believe it was because of this reason, that the CNN on my dataset has a ridiculously low accuracy of around 6%......

I wonder if anyone knows why?

I do not think this is the problem of my dataset (14 classes, amount_of_images = 100-450 for each class, with a total of ~2500 images in the training set), so I will just skip the details about the dataset in this post. I think it is more of a problem related to the CNN...?

I have designed my CNN architecture as below:

```
# Our input feature map is 150x150x3: 150x150 for the image pixels, and 3 for
# the three color channels: R, G, and B
img_input = layers.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
print(img_input)

# First convolution extracts 16 filters that are 3x3
# Convolution is followed by max-pooling layer with a 2x2 window
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same')(img_input)
# x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
print(x)

# Second convolution extracts 32 filters that are 3x3
# Convolution is followed by max-pooling layer with a 2x2 window
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu',strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
# x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
print(x)

# Third convolution extracts 64 filters that are 3x3
# Convolution is followed by max-pooling layer with a 2x2 window
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
# x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
print(x)

# forth convolution extracts 128 filters that are 3x3
# Convolution is followed by max-pooling layer with a 2x2 window
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
# x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
print(x)

#fifth convolution extracts 256 filters that are 3x3
#Convolution is followed by max-pooling layer with a 2x2 window
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
# x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
print(x)
```

which could be seen as the following:

```
Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 150, 150, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv2d/Relu:0", shape=(?, 150, 150, 16), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv2d_1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 75, 75, 32), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv2d_2/Relu:0", shape=(?, 38, 38, 64), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv2d_3/Relu:0", shape=(?, 19, 19, 128), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv2d_4/Relu:0", shape=(?, 10, 10, 256), dtype=float32)
```

then

```
# Flatten feature map to a 1-dim tensor so we can add fully connected layers
x = layers.Flatten()(x)

# Create a fully connected layer with ReLU activation and 512 hidden units
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

# Create output layer with a single node and sigmoid activation
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# Create model:
# input = input feature map
# output = input feature map + stacked convolution/maxpooling layers + fully 
# connected layer + sigmoid output layer
model = Model(img_input, output)
```

These are the results for each epoch:

```
Epoch 1/15
126/126 - 92s - loss: -4.6284e+13 - acc: 0.0647 - val_loss: -3.0235e+14 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 2/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -3.6250e+15 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -1.2503e+16 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 3/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -4.7133e+16 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -1.2015e+17 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 4/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -3.0991e+17 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -6.4998e+17 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 5/15
126/126 - 51s - loss: -1.3102e+18 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -2.4530e+18 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 6/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -4.2291e+18 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -7.3530e+18 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 7/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -1.1655e+19 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -1.8978e+19 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 8/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -2.8185e+19 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -4.3459e+19 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 9/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -6.0396e+19 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -9.0798e+19 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 10/15
126/126 - 51s - loss: -1.2250e+20 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -1.7633e+20 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 11/15
126/126 - 49s - loss: -2.2829e+20 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -3.2223e+20 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 12/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -4.0790e+20 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -5.5966e+20 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 13/15
126/126 - 51s - loss: -6.9094e+20 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -9.3551e+20 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 14/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -1.1305e+21 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -1.5039e+21 - val_acc: 0.0615
Epoch 15/15
126/126 - 50s - loss: -1.7871e+21 - acc: 0.0639 - val_loss: -2.3466e+21 - val_acc: 0.0615
```

I'll also attached the two graphs here for the loss and accuracy:

[image]

[image]

It is basically the model form one of the [Google ML Crash Course](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part1.ipynb?utm_source=practicum-IC&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&hl=en&utm_content=imageexercise1-colab#scrollTo=-5tES8rXFjux), I just changed the parameters here and there and apply my own data to see what would happen.

My theory is that due to unknown reasons, CNN is not extracting any features from my dataset, thus the network found the local minimum in just 2 epochs.

Any help would be greatly appreciate as I am scratching my head to this problem.

Comment: How many epochs did you train the model.?

Comment: @SreeramTP Thanks for the reply, I updated the post with more info.

Comment: Looking at the feature maps makes no sense at this point because the model has not learned anything, your loss is huge and negative, what exact loss function and task (input/output data) are you using? Negative loss is a big red flag that something is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes no sense if you have 14 classes:

```
# Create output layer with a single node and sigmoid activation
output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

You should use softmax activation with 14 neurons:

```
output = layers.Dense(14, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Then you should make sure to use the correct loss (categorical or sparse cross-entropy), and to one-hot encode the labels correctly if needed by the loss.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I always suspect with replacing the binary cross-entropy with categorical or sparse cross-entropy, and the softmax for activation and I am aware that the softmax was being used for the MNIST dataset.
It must be a really stupid question to ask but I am struggling to grasp the right concept about CNN (and anything about deep learning) as the knowledges are so fragmented across the internet.